# Ubuntu 18.04 freezes randomly all the time

Tags: dual-boot

I am dual booting Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and Windows 10 on my Dell laptop. It always freezes randomly at any point in time and when it does, absolutely no command will make it recover. The only way out is to force shutdown. I had a similar experience with Ubuntu 19 which made me to downgrade to 18. Please how can I stop this problem permanently?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What should I do when Ubuntu freezes?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4408/what-should-i-do-when-ubuntu-freezes)

Comment: "It always freezes randomly at any point in time" that is nothing to go on. "Please how can I stop this problem permanently?" Find the cause. Start by digging through the log files in /var/log/ There is likely a notice there with CRITICAL in it. Or "core dumped".

Comment: @Rinzwind Sorry I am kind of new to using Ubuntu and I am not sure of how to find the cause of my problem. How do I get to /var/log/

Comment: The same way you navigate to any other directory. Use your File Manager.